# How much time is appropriate 7-year-old to play "Fit in Six" on the PS3?

Tags: workout-routines, children, video-games

How much daily time is appropriate for a child of 7 years to do the routines in the game "Fit in Six" on the PlayStation 3?

My son is thin, but is very active and likes these routines. However, I do not know to what extent such exercises are safe and healthy; I do not permit it every day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I was six or seven, I played outside, running and climbing trees and fences until I  "needed" to go home because it was getting dark or my parentally-imposed time-limit for fun had arrived. As long as you're child isn't getting drenched in his clothing - he should be ok.

If you're worried about him being exposed to an extreme amount of exercise, note that there are leagues/clubs all over the US for youths his age to do just about every event in Track & Field. www.USATF.org will likely have information on it. I doubt the PS3 trumps that level of exertion.

Comment: I would agree.  Just make sure he eats well and gets enough fluids if he gets too addicted.